# Как сделать скрипт для Google-таблиц, который по ссылке на файлы, создаёт один сводный файл?

Tags: google-apps-script

Необходимо доработать/исправить `script`,  который в `google-таблицах`, основываясь на ссылках на файлы `(ссылки находятся лист - №3, столбец А)` записывает данные (первые четыре столбца) построчно, без пропусков, на лист `"СВОД"`
Писал дилетант, но понять, почему не работает, не можем..

```
var i = 2;
var g = 2;
var h = 2;
var rs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var svod = rs.getSheetByName('Свод');
var sheet1 = rs.getSheetByName('Лист1');
var sheet2 = rs.getSheetByName('Лист2');
var sheet3 = rs.getSheetByName('Лист3');

function superfunc() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheet3.getRange("A" + i).getValue());
  var Dinam = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2');

  for (h = 2; h <= 4; h++) {

    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheet3.getRange("A" + i).getValue());

    Dinam = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2');

    for (g = 2; g <= sheet1.getRange(1, 7).getValue(); g++) {

      svod.getRange("A" + i).setValue(Dinam.getRange("A" + g).getValue());
      svod.getRange("B" + i).setValue(Dinam.getRange("B" + g).getValue());
      svod.getRange("C" + i).setValue(Dinam.getRange("C" + g).getValue());
      svod.getRange("D" + i).setValue(Dinam.getRange("D" + g).getValue());
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что c такими вопросами нужно идти на биржу фрилансеров

Comment: @norbornen, таки Max и есть от тудова. На ruSO же бесплатно - маржа в карман. Заказать решение можно тут https://t.me/googleappsscriptrc или тут https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/103356854721490738172